# How to troubleshoot authentication with ActiveDirectory server

Tags: php, laravel, active-directory, ldap, adldap

I am trying to make authentication with ActiveDirectory using ldaprecord-laravel. I followed the [documentation](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v2) and made required changes in files. However, I ended up with only `php artisan ldap:test` working and `php artisan ldap:import ldap` showing that there are no users to import.

When I use online LDAP test server, I can go further and make `Auth::attempt(['uid' => 'einstein', 'password' => 'password'])` in Tinker, and import works, but the web login still doesn't work. With AD, I can't auth attempt using neither `samaccountname`, nor `username`, nor `uid`. Though plain auth using `ldap_connect` and `ldap_bind` works.

### App/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; 
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\LdapAuthenticatable;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\AuthenticatesWithLdap;

class User extends Authenticatable implements LdapAuthenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, AuthenticatesWithLdap;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

    /*
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return Hash::make( $this->user_pass );
    }
    */

    /**
     * Настройки пользователя.
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function settings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Models\Settings::class, 'id', 'id');
    }

}
```

### App/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\ListensForLdapBindFailure;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers, ListensForLdapBindFailure;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Переопределяем переменную, в которой хранится логин пользователя
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'user_login';
    }

    /**
     * Валидация данных на сервере
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }  

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'uid' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I find out what causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting in Laravel is usually done with [logging](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging). According to the given document, you may log string using

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

// somewhere in the code
Log::debug('info string');
```

Laravel puts it's logs in `storage/logs` folder. There are such entries in the log:

```
[2021-08-24 10:41:13] local.INFO: LDAP (ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389) - Operation: Bound - Username: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com  
[2021-08-24 10:35:54] local.INFO: LDAP (ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389) - Operation: Search - Base DN: dc=example,dc=com - Filter: (&(objectclass=\74\6f\70)(objectclass=\70\65\72\73\6f\6e)(objectclass=\6f\72\67\61\6e\69\7a\61\74\69\6f\6e\61\6c\70\65\72\73\6f\6e)(objectclass=\69\6e\65\74\6f\72\67\70\65\72\73\6f\6e)(uid=)) - Selected: (entryuuid,*) - Time Elapsed: 471.78
```

We see that `uid` is not given, and it is because we use `user_login` instead of `username`, so the final decision was to change LoginController.php:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'uid' => $request->user_login,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];
}
```

After doing that, logging in was successful.